# Is the diaphragm made of two muscles?

Tags: human-anatomy

Is there a 'crural' and 'costal' parts of the diaphragm as suggested in [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1046/j.1469-7580.2002.00095.x) or is it just a single muscle?

Comment: @aliential so it's incorrect to consider there to be a 'crural' part of the diaphragm?

Comment: @aliential please do not answer in the comments; comments are reserved for comments, answers for answers. Comments are used to ask for clarifications or to suggest edits. Answers are there to answer the question. Placing answers in comments repels other users to generate a proper answer.

Comment: The delineation of muscles is often arbitrary. E.g., quadriceps femoris can be thought of as one muscle or four, depending on how you look at it. A debate over semantics is generally not useful in these situations. Understanding the crux of the matter is more important. In this particular paper, the crux is that the costal and crural parts of the diaphragms work somewhat independently in certain activities.